# Requirements for using NetStream.seek()

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, seekbar, flex4.6, netstream

I'm using a NetStream class to play video using Video class  or stage video , there is no seek bar to backward or forward video , i add seek bar to video but the seek function not work exactly , it give me a wrong time of seeking . `ns.seek(mySeekTime)`
i wondered if it possible to make my own seek bar with exact seeking , i get the video from server , is server affect on seeking for video ?

```
        private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
             if (event.currentTarget is Group)
             {
                 var myGroup:Group = event.currentTarget as Group;
                 if ( myGroup.mouseX >= 100)
                  {
                     mouseClickedXPos = myGroup.mouseX;
                     ns.inBufferSeek = true;
                     var seekTime:Number = (mouseClickedXPos-100) * (totalTime/(controlBarControls.width-100));
                     ns.seek(seekTime);     
                     myRect.graphics.clear();
                     myRect.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                     myRect.graphics.drawRect(controlBarControls.x+100,controlBarControls.y,mouseClickedXPos-100, rect.height);
                 }  
             }
        }
```

Here seek bar is myRect shape i draw it after Event.ENTER_FRAME .

problem : the time `ns.time()` will not change to new time we updated by seek(seekTime)

Comment: You will get more responses if you post code, and the exact problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add keyframes to the video in ex. Adobe Media Encoder? It seems that seek function uses keyframes to locate the time.

Comment: NetStream can only seek to keyframes.  If you have keyframes every six seconds and then seek to time 10 the video will end up playing at time 6.